# How do you give people prefixes for their usernames?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

How do you give people tags/prefixes on your Minecraft server? I have a server but I do not know how to make it say I am the owner in the chat.

Example: `Owner Kieranpb7: <text>`

Comment: I am pretty sure you require a plugin for this. Do you have a bukkit server?

Comment: I think this is possible through the use of scoreboard and teams, I will test it out and get back to you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible in vanilla Minecraft but requires the use of a third-party program called NBTExplorer.

First, open the world and add a team for each prefix to be used (e.g. owner, donator, etc). The command is:

`/scoreboard teams add [name] [displayname]`

Or in your case: `/scoreboard teams add owners Owner`

Exit the world. Next, download NBTExplorer from [here.](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac) Open it up.

Select your world within the `.minecraft/saves`. Navigate to `data > scoreboard.dat > data > Teams`

Inside that, there should be several `7 entries` or `9 entries`. Each of these represents a team, open it up and look at the `Name` and `DisplayName` entries to tell which is which.

There should be other entries in this: one called `Prefix` and another called `Suffix`. Edit the prefix so it says `[OWNER] §r` MAKE SURE YOU PUT THE SPACE AND COPY-PASTE THE §r! The `[OWNER]` part can be anything you like though, but for visibility, I recommend `[text]` so that it is easily told apart from the username. You can also add a suffix if you like which will be displayed after the username.

Press the save button at the top, and reload the world. Join the team with `/scoreboard teams join owners [playername]` and test it out in chat!

I hope this helps!

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of NBTExplorer]

Answer (score 3):

In 1.14, the process described by angussidney is a lot simpler. Use `/scoreboard teams add [name] [displayname]` to make a team, and then use `/team modify [name] [prefix|suffix] "prefix/suffix"` to add a prefix or suffix. The [`/team modify`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/team) command lets you change lots of other things besides prefixes and suffixes as well.