# Chat prefixes in Minecraft without plugins?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make chat prefixes (like so):

```
Steve (Administrator): Hello
```

That is in the chat.

In this, Steve is the username and Administrator is the rank.
I want to do this without plugins or mods, just commands. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you give people prefixes for their usernames?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212309/how-do-you-give-people-prefixes-for-their-usernames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, this is impossible, unless you would use a NBT editor, such NBTexplorer.

This technique uses teams, so you will need to create a team. `/scoreboard teams` (for options press tab)

If you want to look at the file/path on NBT Explorer (it's probably compatable with other programs):

> saves\custom world name here\scoreboard.dat\teams\X entries\Prefix

now edit Prefix. This is what you want

If you want color codes, visit the wiki:
[Formatting Codes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes)

For example,
`§f[§e§lOWNER§f]`

Would be <Owner> (when Owner is bold yellow, the rest is plain white)

Comment: would this be possible on Minecraft Realms?

Comment: I do not know as I do not own a realm anynore, but as long as you upload the world then most likely yes. You can do this do an existing world by downloading it and than editing.

Comment: :D no problem. If you want to do this on a great scale, I would suggest a bukkit server, as their are much easier ways to do this such as the PEX plugin. But considering that your on a realm, this wont be nessecary.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the user's name.
The chat is always formatted like as `<pseudo> : message` (excluding CommandBlocks `say` or `tellraw` option)

In order to change it, you NEED to change the program. Even for typing the `§` character (for formating text), you need a third-party program or changing a .class file.